# Is there an analytical approach to solve this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation in question is:

$$\dot y(t) = A e^{-at} + B (1-e^{-at}) + y(t) (C e^{-at}+D(1 - e^{-at})) $$

Comment: I think a parenthesis is missing Mr. Heisenberg!

Comment: MMA gives this here $$y(t)=e^{\frac{(e-C) e^{-a t}}{a}+e t} \int_1^t \left(B e^{a
   K[1]}+A-B\right) \exp \left(-\frac{(e-C) e^{-a
   K[1]}}{a}-a K[1]-e K[1]\right) \, dK[1]+c_1
   e^{\frac{(e-C) e^{-a t}}{a}+e t}$$

Comment: I believe that might be the same solution as the one proposed by Mohammad Riazi-Kermani. I should give up in getting an analytic solution. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differential equation

$$\dot y(t) = A e^{-at} + B (1-e^{-at}) + y(t) (C e^{-at}+D(1 - e^{-at}))$$

is a linear equation so theoretically it has a solution which could be found by the integrating factor method.

However the integrals are not easy ones and the solution has to involve some integrals which do not have simple solutions.

Comment: Thank you, I do indeed get integrals that are not easy to solve.

Comment: Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy if you know Laplace transforms. The hardest part is to isolate y(s).

We have $$ \dot{y(t)}=Ae^{-at}+B(1-e^{-at})+y(t)(Ce^{-at}+D(1-e^{-at})) $$

Taking the laplace transform of both sides:

$$ sY(s)-y(0)=\frac{A}{s+a}+B(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s+a})+Y(s)(\frac{C}{s+a}+D(\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s+a})) $$

After having this equation in the Laplace domain isolate Y(s) and then apply the inverse Laplace transform and you get y(t).

Comment: I believe the Laplace transform of $y(t) e^{-a t}$ is $Y(s+a)$, which makes the problem harder to solve.